# MVC4 - Model binding/mapping to parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I've defined the validation of two fields on a model by using the *RemoteAttribute*. The value for each text-box is sent to the server successfully but as a different named object in each instance. This is a good default but I want to re-use the same remote method for numerous fields. How do I tell MVC to bind/map ***PrimaryEmail*** and ***SecondaryEmail*** to the ***email*** property on the server-side?

Tried this and it doesn't work: (email is always null)

Model:

```
public class UserModel {
    [Remote("EmailCheck", "Profile", HttpMethod = "post", ErrorMessage = "The email is already in use.")]
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    [Remote("EmailCheck", "Profile", HttpMethod = "post", ErrorMessage = "The email is already in use.")]
    public string SecondaryEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Server side Action:

```
public JsonResult EmailCheck([Bind(Include = "PrimaryEmail, SecondaryEmail")]string email)
{
    return Json(!_serviceManager.UserProfileService.IsEmailInUse(email));
}
```

JSON sent to the server:

```
PrimaryEmail=abc%40yahoo.com
SecondaryEmail=abc%40yahoo.com
```

Comment: There are two text boxes on the screen; one for PrimaryEmail and one for SecondaryEmail. They are **not** sent at the same time. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is in control of what's sent to the server. This is all out-of-the-box. As you type into _PrimaryEmail_ it will send the JSON `PrimaryEmail=abc%40yahoo.com` and when you type in _SecondaryEmail_ it will send this JSON `SecondaryEmail=abc%40yahoo.com`. Both validate using the _EmailCheck_ action on the server. I just need to bind/map the JSON names to the _email_ parameter.

Comment: I understand now, I looked up what the `RemoteAttribute` was for and realized my question was unnecessary.

Comment: It certainly seems like using the `Bind` attribute should do the trick, though I wonder how that attribute resolves the binding when two or more of the names in the `Include` list have a value.

Comment: I think the other option, though more of a hack, would be to give the two HTML inputs corresponding to the emails the same name of `email`.  Having two elements with the same name is legal in HTML and should allow the value to bind properly in the action method.  Only other thing to figure out would be what to do if/when you post the whole form containing both values.  Possibly a javascript hack to change the names back to correspond to their properties.